# Pass python variable into os.system(gnome-terminal) command

Tags: python, bash, gnome-terminal

How can I pass a python variable into the gnome-terminal command option ? I want to open multiple terminal with a specific command.

Here is the code (an example) of what I want to do :

```
cmd = "echo OK"
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"'cmd' ; exec bash\"'")
```

But it's not working because the shell tries to interpret the command "cmd" (bash : cmd: command not found)

Can you help me please ?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You could use format to replace your variable into the string :

```
cmd = "echo OK"
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"'{}' ; exec bash\"'".format(cmd))
```

Comment: I have done a modification :
     `os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \'{}' ; exec bash \'".format(cmd))`

Because your command returned an error. Nothing happens. I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're passing the string "*cmd*" not the variable `cmd = "echo OK"`. Try out this.

```
cmd = "echo OK"
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c " + cmd + " ; exec bash'")
```

**EDIT>**

Maybe the module `subprocess` can help you. Try this snippet.

```
import subprocess    
cmd_line = "echo Hello!"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out = p.communicate()[0]
print out
```

Comment: This is working but not it's not exactly what I expect. In fact, I want multiple window with new terminal.